Why can't I RDP to machines in my subnet by machine name, yet IP address works? Works fine with a different admin account, just not my main
I have a strange issue that started happening a couple weeks ago and I just can't figure it out. When I try to use RDP to access any machine on the same subnet as my workstation it fails with an error that says my credentials are no good. This happens only if I access the machine by name. If I access by IP address, it connects fine. I can connect with my main account to machines in other subnets, across the VPN without issue as well. What makes it even more odd is that if I ping the machine by name, it is returning the correct IP. My account is a domain admin account and it is only happening with my main login or profile. If I switch to another domain admin account, it connects just fine by machine name. Also, if I log into the machine directly at the server using my main account, also no issue. I wonder if it is an AD issue. Does anyone have any idea what may be the issue?

Do you use the FQDN or just the short DNS name to connect to it ?

I use FQDN and it makes no difference. Still complains about the credentials. It says "The credentials that were used to connect to  did not work. Please enter new credentials.

Looks like a Kerberos issue (Kerberos is used when calling a machine by name but not when calling it by IP address).

It can happen after that patch ((https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5008380-authentication-updates-cve-2021-42287-9dafac11-e0d0-4cb8-959a-143bd0201041), but it's an old patch.. do you have older DC alive or an old domain functionnal level ? Check your eventlog to see Kerberos's error in all case

I have two DCs and both are running Server 2016. I checked and the domain functional level was set to 2012. I raised it to 2016 and then I was able to remote into the DC in my subnet normally, so that is progress. I still cannot remote into some of my VMs, but I find that a reboot of one of those non-essential VMs did allow me to remote it as normal again. I think this is resolving the issue. Thanks for the help!

Thanks to the suggestion by yagmoth555, I checked the domain functional level in Active Directory Domains and Trusts and it was set to Server 2012. Since both of my DCs have since been upgraded to Server 2016, I set both the domain and forest functional levels to Server 2016 and the issue is now resolved.
